# I want to open webpages within android app?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-webview

I have created an application and data of user is loaded via firebase recycler adapter. It have data of users and each user have a link in their profile which redirect to a webpage. Everything is working fine the user is redirected to the webpage via the default browser. My question is how can I restrict the app to open the links/urls within itself. I don't want the links to be opened in the default browser. Below is my code

**MyViewholder**

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView geglink, userName, userAbout;
    View v;


    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        geglink = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcvGigLink);
        userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcvName);
        userAbout = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcvAbout);
        v = itemView;
```

**DashboardActivity**

```
  RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ModelClass> options;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelClass, MyViewHolder> adapter;
    DatabaseReference dRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.dashboardRCV);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

      LoadData();

    }

    private void LoadData() {
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelClass>()
                .setQuery(dRef, ModelClass.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelClass, MyViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ModelClass model) {
                holder.geglink.setText(model.getGig());
                holder.userName.setText(model.getName());
                holder.userAbout.setText(model.getAbout());

                holder.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String url = model.getGig();
                if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")){
                    url = "https://" + url;
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout, parent, false);
                return new MyViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        adapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**ModelClass**

```
public class ModelClass {

    String gig, name, about;

    public String getGig() {
        return gig;
    }

    public void setGig(String gig) {
        this.gig = gig;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }

    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }

    public ModelClass(String gig, String name, String about) {
        this.gig = gig;
        this.name = name;
        this.about = about;
    }

    public ModelClass() {
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not use ACTION_VIEW to begin with as with that intent you bring it outside your application to another app the user chooses.

Comment: `restrict the app to open the links/urls within itself` Does your op know how to display a html page?

Comment: So what should I use instead of ACTION_VIEW?

Comment: `Does your app know how to display a html page?

Comment: I have not implemented any functionality for displaying HTML pages and frankly I don't know how to do this as I am new to android studio.

Comment: You can display html files in a WebView component.

Comment: You mean I'll have to create a webview?

Comment: Google did that for you. You can just use one in your app.